# Did Lord Shiva have any children from Sati?

Tags: shiva, goddess

Most of us know about Shiva and Parvati has children. But, Shiva has any children from Sati (they gonna be born before Daksha Yajna)?

If yes, what are these name and Which scripture give their details?